# How to get list of updating attributes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following code:

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, if:  :some_method?

def some_method?

end
```

For my `some_method?` I need to get list of attributes which are being passed to update. How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ActiveRecord::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) might be what you are looking for.

Before you save the update to the database, `obj.changes` returns a hash of all modified attributes with a key of the attribute name, and an array of `[from, to]` for the newly assigned (but not saved) value.